# Generation of a sequence of adjacent repeated values in an array

Tags: arrays, object, boolean, conditional-statements, sequence

So I got a task to do the program where I have to generate 20 tosses using another class of Die(). Class Die() basically generates random numbers through multiple methods (nothing wrong with that class).

The main idea is to generate a sequence of 20 die tosses in an array using the Die(); in addition to that I have to initially set boolean inRun; (that's where I had the issue).

Output should look like:    1 2 (5 5) 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 (5 5) 6 (3 3)

I do get the idea that there's something wrong with the boolean, and it's pretty simple, but oh well, just stuck))))

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

    Die toss = new Die();
    int[] t = new int[21];
    boolean inRun=false;

    for (int i =0; i<t.length-1;i++) {
        toss.roll();
        t[i]=toss.getFaceValue();

        if (inRun) {

            if (t[i]!=t[i-1]) {//c1
                System.out.print(") ");
                inRun = false;
            }
        }//end of inrun


        else {
            if (t[i]==t[i+1]) {
                System.out.println(" ("+t[i]);
                inRun=true;
            }
        }


        System.out.print(t[i]);
    }//for loop

    if (inRun) {
        System.out.print(" )");
    }


}//end method
```